# Self convolutions of singular continuous measure

Tags: measure-theory, convolution

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Define the measures $(\mu_n)_{n\geq 1}$ by $\mu_{n+1}=\mu\ast \mu_n$ and $\mu_1=\mu$

Is there a singular (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) continuous measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\geq 2$, $\mu_n$ is also singular continuous ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple explicit example of a measure $\mu$ with all convolution powers singular: let $\mu$ be the distribution of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k 2^{-k!}, 
$$
where the $X_k$ are IID taking values $0$ and $1$ with equal probability. The support of $\mu$ is the set $A$ of points whose binary expansion has non-zero digits only at places $k!,k\in\mathbb{N}$. Using this, it follows easily  that for each $n$, the $n$-fold arithmetic sum $A^{+n}=A+\ldots+A$ has zero Lebesgue measure (in fact it has zero Hausdorff dimension), since the binary expansion of points in $A^{+n}$ must have zeros at all places not of the form $k!+j$ for some $0\le j\le n$.  Since the convolution power $\mu^{*n}$ is supported on $A^{+n}$, it must be purely singular. On the other hand, $\mu$ has no atoms so neither does $\mu^{*n}$. This example doesn't use the Fourier transform at all.

Let me also give complete details of why the Cantor-Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on the middle-thirds Cantor set is an example of a measure all of whose self-convolutions are purely singular (but continuous, since $\mu$ itself already has no atoms).

Recall that $\mu$ can be realized as the distribution of the random sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i 3^{-i}$, where $X_i$ are independent random variables taking the values $0$ and $2$ with equal probability. In particular, 
$$
\widehat{\mu}(\xi) =\prod_{i=1}^\infty \cos(2\pi 3^{-i}\xi)
$$
from which it easily follows that $\widehat{\mu}(\xi)$ doesn't decay to $0$ as $\xi\to\infty$ (this also follows from the fact that $\mu$ is invariant under multiplication by $3$ on the circle). Hence, if $\mu^{*n}$ denotes the $n$-fold self-convolution, then $\widehat{\mu^{*n}}(\xi)=\widehat{\mu}(\xi)^n$ also doesn't decay to $0$, so $\mu^{*n}$ cannot be absolutely continuous by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Now, recall that a Borel probability measure $\nu$ on the real line is called *self-similar* if there are contracting similarities $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ and a probability vector $(p_1,\ldots,p_m)$ such that
$$
\nu(A)= \sum_{j=1}^m p_i\, \nu(f_j^{-1}(A)).
$$
Given the tuples $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ and $(p_1,\ldots,p_m)$ there is exactly one Borel probability measure satisfying the above identity; this follows from seeing the right-hand side as a contracting operator on an appropriate Banach space (actually we only care about uniqueness, so we only need to have a contraction, no completeness is required).

If $\nu$ is a self-similar measure as above, then the absolutely continuous and singular parts of $\nu$ are seen to satisfy the same self-similarity relation. By the uniqueness of $\nu$, one of these parts has to be trivial. So self-similar measures are either absolutely continuous or purely singular with respect to Lebesgue.

To conclude, I claim that $\mu^{*n}$ is a self-similar measure for every $n$. Since we already established that $\mu^{*n}$ cannot be absolutely continuous, this will show that it must be purely singular.

By definition, $\mu^{*n}$ is the distribution of the random sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty Y_i^{(n)} 3^{-i},
$$
where the $Y_j^{(n)}$ are IID with the distribution of the sum of $n$ independent realizations of $X_i$ (defined above). In particular, the distribution of $Y_i^{(n)}$ has the form $\sum_{j=0}^{n} p_j^{(n)} \delta_{2j}$ for some probability vector $p_j$. It can then be easily checked that $\mu^{*n}$ is the self-similar measure corresponding to the contractions $(x/3+2j)_{j=0}^{n}$ an the probability vector $(p_j)_{j=0}^n$.

Let me mention that it follows from work of Garsia in the 60s that not only $\mu^{*n}$ is singular for all $n$, but in fact for each $n$ there is a Borel set $A_n$ of Hausdorff dimension strictly less than $1$ such that $\mu^{*n}(A_n)=1$ (the topological support of $\mu^{*n}$ is an interval for all $n\ge 2$). On the other hand, the Hausdorff dimension of $A_n$ must tend to $1$; this follows from recent work of M. Hochman.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, indeed. You can build a one dimensional family of non-atomic singular measures on $[0,1]$ simply by pushing the Bernoully measure with parameter $p$ with the help of the dyadic decomposition of real numbers.

Start with $X_i$ iid random variables such that $P(X_i = 1) = p = 1 - P(X_i = 0)$ and define
$$
Y_p = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty {X_i\over 2^i}
$$
The law of $Y_{1/2}$ is the Lebesgue measure. For other values of $p$ however, it is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure because it is supported by the set $\{ \sum {x_i \over 2^i} \mid {1\over n} \sum_k x_k \rightarrow p\}$ by the strong law of large numbers and these sets are disjoints for different values of $p$.

The same remark shows that $Y_p + Y'_p$ is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure if $Y_p$ and $Y'_p$  are independent with the same law (associated to $X_i$ and $X'_i$ iid Bernoulli) and $E(Y_p+Y'_p) = 2p \neq {1}$. And so on. So just take $p\neq 2$ and the law of $Y_p$ is such that all its products are non-atomic singular.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was looking for something like that. However it seems to me that you can suppose that $E(Yp+Y′p)=2p≠1$ because $Y_p+Y'_p$ lives in $[0,2]$

Comment: Indeed. Corrected.

Comment: So we just need to pick $p\neq \frac12$ and all the products are non-atomic singular.

Comment: Yes. You can also consider the product of $Y_p$ for different $p$ and this is singular e.g. if the p's don't give a rational number. This is really something that happens on the symbolic space $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$. We are just charging the digits with different weights.

Comment: Indeed. By the way, is the Hausdorff dimension of the support of $Y_p$ easy to compute ?

Comment: Is it clear that these remain singular as you sum them?

Comment: This is given by the entropy. $h(\mu_p) = p\ln(1/p) + (1-p)\ln(1/(1-p))$. See the book of Parry on information theory for the computation. This is a particular case of a formula relating the entropy, the Lyapunov exponent of the underlying system (here the shift) and the dimension of the invariant measure.

Comment: I don't see this. I think I believe the claim, but I don't think you have supplied a full proof.

Comment: I guess you can argue this way: the $n$-fold convolution of mixing *2-invariant measures is another mixing *2-invariant measure. The **only** absolutely continuous *2-invariant measure is Lebesgue, so as long as the convolution is not equal to Lebesgue, it must be singular.

Comment: @Quas Indeed I have not supplied a full proof. I thought there was a simple argument, but I was a bit too fast apparently. As far as I remember, the Fourier transform does not go to 0 and this can be shown by an explicit albeit lengthy computation. The Fourier transform of $\mu_p$ is equal to the one of $\mu_{1/2}$ together with an infinite product whose log can be evaluated using the ergodic theorem for $\times 2$ along a sequence $t_N = 2^N\pi\theta$ for a.e. $\theta$.

Comment: @Remling Ah, indeed. And I can't reproduce the computation of the FT. So I don't see a way to show that the products are singular.

Comment: @Remling The argument outlined by Anthony Quas using ×2 works on the circle [0,1[≃R/Z (the products are again invariant by ×2) but not on R. I don't know how to prove that the products are indeed singular on R. So I think Baire wins at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this (the existence of such an example, that is) cheaply from some abstract nonsense, though I would certainly prefer a direct example.

If you put the weak $*$ topology on the probability measures, then the generic measure is purely singular continuous. In other words, the set of purely sc measures contains a dense $G_{\delta}$. In fact, here I need the more specific information that both $\{\mu: \mu_{ac}=0\}$ and $\{ \mu: \mu_{pp}=0\}$ are $G_{\delta}$'s (and dense, which is obvious), which is how the statement I just quoted is usually proved. See also Thms 1.1, 1.2 [here.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2118629.pdf)

Since $f_n: \mu \mapsto \mu * \mu * \ldots * \mu$ is continuous, the set $\{ \mu: f_n(\mu)_{xx}=0 \}$ still contains a dense $G_{\delta}$ set, for both $xx=ac$ and $xx=pp$. So $f_n(\mu)$ is purely singular continuous on at least a dense $G_{\delta}$ of $\mu$'s.

Since we have only countably many conditions, what you want also happens on at least a dense $G_{\delta}$ set.

Answer (score 1):

A pisot number is an algebraic integer all of whose conjugates are < 1 in magnitude.  If $X_i$ are i.i.d, symmetric,  $\pm 1$ random variables and $\lambda$ is a pisot number look at $\sum \frac {X_i} {\lambda^i}$ whose characteristic function is $\prod cos(\frac {2 \pi t} {\lambda^i})$.  You can show that this does not go to zero at $\infty$.  The key is that for a pisot number $|||\lambda^i||| \rightarrow 0$ exponentially fast, where that norm is distance to the nearest  integer, so look in a $t =  \lambda^N$.   If it does not go 0 no power of it does either, so no power is absolutely continuous.  As to it's singularity, I think it follow from the law of pure types, but it is easily proven in case $\lambda > 2$ in which case $\sum^N \frac {X_i} {\lambda^i}$ consists of $2^N$ distinct equally weighted points.

Comment: The standard example of a Pisot number is the golden mean.

Comment: @Chr: this answer is convincing to me. In essence, it says that the Fourier transform of an absolutely continuous measure has the property that it decays to 0 as $t\to\infty$ (this is the Riemann Lebesgue lemma). This fails for this example (compute the Fourier transform at $\lambda^n$). But since the Fourier transform of the $n$-fold convolution is just the $n$th power of the Fourier transform of $\mu$, the same argument shows that $\mu^{*n}$ is singular.

Comment: I think this only proves that the measures are never purely absolutely continuous. They could be purely singular (and even atomic) or the sum of an absolutely continuous measure and a singular one.

Comment: Hmm.  True. I believe there are purity laws for infinite convolutions, though, so it should be possible to salvage an answer.atomic is impossible, as the convolution of non-atomic with anything is non-atomic.

Comment: Chr, good point.  In fact I had in mind a proof that the measure was non atomic.

Comment: So apparently Jessen and Wintner proved in 1935 that the convolution of discrete measures is of pure type. www.math.uchicago.edu/~schlag/papers/sixty.pdf

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, that's correct, also in this case the convolutions are all self-similar, and self-similar measures are also known to be either purely singular or mutually absolutely continuous to Lebesgue

Comment: Also, the same argument (even easier) shows that the Cantor-Lebesgue measure on the middle-thirds Cantor set is an example that answers the OP's question

Comment: @Pablo I think I understand what you mean but why is the middle-third Cantor set a good example ? Is it clear that its Fourier transform does not go to zero ?

Comment: @Chr: Yes, because this FT equals $\prod \cos (3^{-n}x)$.

Comment: @PabloShmerkin: I don't see how this answer addresses the point that Chr raised above and that was also discussed at some length in the comments to coudy's answer: why does the $n$-fold convolution of (let's say) the Cantor measure not have an ac part? From the fact that the FT doesn't go to zero, we can only conclude that this measure isn't *purely* ac.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, this is addressed in the comments: these measures are of pure type (either abs. continuous or purely singular) because they are infinite convolutions of discrete measures, or because they are self-similar. See my new answer for a detailed explanation using the latter fact.