# Convoluted Cantor-like measure which has a continuous component

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb R$ which has no atoms, and no component continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. An example is the law of the random variable
$$
 \sum_{k\ge 1}3^{-k}X_k
$$
where the $X_k$ are IID Bernoulli (0-1 valued) random variables, because $\mu$ only charges numbers which ternary expansion contains only $0$s and $1$s.

Is it always possible to find $n\ge 1$ such that the $n-$th convolution product of $\mu$, denoted by $\mu^{\otimes n}$, has a non-zero component with respect to Lebesgue measure? With the example above, the answer is yes with $n=2$ because if one takes $X_n'$ independent copies of the $X_n$, then $\mu^{\otimes 2}$ is the law of
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1}3^{-k}(X_k+X_k'),
$$
which charges all ternary expansions.

On the other hand, my experience with ugly measures is that the answer should be no, but I can't find a counter-example...

Comment: Your example could be something like $\sum X_k/k!$, with $X_k$ IID Bernoulli.

Comment: Is this different from the the question "Self convolutions of singular continuous mesure"?                                                                                      https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266450/self-convolutions-of-singular-continuous-measure

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can a absolutely continuous measure convolving finitely many cantors.  The fourier transform for the cantor measure is $ \hat f = \Pi cos(\frac  {2 \pi  t}  {3^n}) $ and it has the feature that $\hat f(3^n) = \hat f (1) $,  esp., it does not go to zero, and therefore nor does any power, showing that no power is absolutely continuous. $$$$  This does not rule out that it might have an absolutely continuous component.  If you want to dispose of that possibility, Gerald's example will $$$$

1. be singular non atomic, and $$$$
2. have the property that the lim sup of $\hat f$ is 1, which will also be true of any power, showing that the measure is singular.

Comment: Thanks! As pointed out, the question is solved by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266450/self-convolutions-of-singular-continuous-measure Everything is on MO!